# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero when computing standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, scipy, divide-by-zero

I've isolated a problem in my script that is occurring due to this attempt at a standard deviation calculation using scipy's .tstd function,

```
 sp.stats.tstd(IR)
```

where my `IR` value is `0.0979`. Is there a way to get this to stop (I assume) rounding it to zero? I've tried a suggestion from a previous stackoverflow post that suggested calling the number an `np.float64` but that didn't work. Hoping someone has the answer.

Full Error printout:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Utt_test.py", line 995, in <module>
    X.write(Averaging())
  File "Utt_test.py", line 115, in Averaging
    IR_sdev=str(round(sp.stats.tstd(IR),4))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 848, in tstd
    return np.sqrt(tvar(a,limits,inclusive))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 755, in tvar
    return a.var()*(n/(n-1.))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: `tstd` requires an input of a numpy array. Hard to calculate a standard deviation of a single number.

Comment: From the error message the problem arise during the computation of ``a.var()*(n/(n-1.))``. Than is the problem is that ``n=1.``. Nothing to do with numpy float or IR...

Comment: I see...hmmmm, gonna have to rewrite some things then. The program usually runs with more than one number. I'm trying a special case.

Comment: That error message is not very helpful, but the real problem is that `tstd` and `tvar` (which is called by `tstd`) need at least two values.

Answer (score 0):

The method `tstd` computes the square root of sample variance. The sample variance differs from the population variance by the factor `n/(n-1)` which is necessary to make sample variance an unbiased estimator for the population variance. This breaks down for n=1, which is understandable because having one number gives us no idea of what the population variance might be.

If this adjustment is undesirable (perhaps your array **is** the total population, and not a sample from it), use [numpy.std](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) instead. For an array of size 1, it will return 0 as expected. If used with parameter ddof=1, `numpy.std` becomes equivalent to `stats.tstd`.

---

Asie: [SciPy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.tstd.html) states

> tstd computes the unbiased sample standard deviation, i.e. it uses a correction factor n / (n - 1).

repeating the common misconception that this standard error estimator is unbiased (in fact, the correction factor eliminates bias for the variance, not for standard deviation).  [NumPy's std documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) turns out to be correct on this point where it discusses `ddof` parameter

> If, however, ddof is specified, the divisor N - ddof is used instead. In standard statistical practice, ddof=1 provides an unbiased estimator of the variance of the infinite population. ddof=0 provides a maximum likelihood estimate of the variance for normally distributed variables. The standard deviation computed in this function is the square root of the estimated variance, so even with ddof=1, it will not be an unbiased estimate of the standard deviation per se.